# How can I change a route in ReactJs depending on a timestamp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

How can I change a route in my reactJs menu.js component from 1 route to another depending on a timestamp.
For example, when it's the 1st of Decembre the following will change:

From:

```
<Link to="/coming-soon">Coming Soon</Link>
```

To:

```
<Link to="/store">Store</Link>
```

I am using a functional component for the menu.js , and I don't have much experience in ReactJs

**UPDATE:**
App.js

```
  return (
    <>
      <Menu />

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <LandingPage />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/coming-soon" exact>
          <ComingSoon />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/store" exact>
          <Store />
        </Route>
    </Switch>

    <Footer />
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Can you please share the code where you have implemented routing? or the one you tried already to achieve this?

Comment: Check the updated question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I notice you want to add a check to update it without refreshing, so I'd adjust the functional component to store the first date in a `const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState(new Date())` and within the useEffect update that with an interval e.g.:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
     setCurrentDate(new Date())
  }, 1000); // set this as you wish on how responsive you wish it to be
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Depending if you already have a date formatting library installed the exact implementation could differ, but for example if you use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.24.0/docs/compareAsc) you are provided lots of helpful utils like:

```js
compareAsc(dateLeft, dateRight)
```

which can be used like so to compare dates, we compare todays date `new Date()` to december 1st `new Date('1/12/2021')`, if the first date is before the second date it returns -1, so the condition is true and we show the coming soon, if its after we return 1, the condition is false and then we show the store:

```js
 return (
  <>
    <Menu />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact>
        <LandingPage />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
    {compareAsc(currentDate, new Date("1/12/2021")) === -1 ? (
      <Route path="/coming-soon" exact>
        <ComingSoon />
      </Route>
    ) : (
      <Route path="/store" exact>
        <Store />
      </Route>
    )}
    <Footer />
  </>
)
```

Not that it's necessarily recommended to pull a package for everything - but for dates these provide lots of handy utils so getting used to all that they have to offer can be useful if you haven't seen them yet!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set route path dynamically when you get timestamp changed, at that time you can use like below

```
<Link to="/${yourdynamicpath}">{Title}</Link>
```

Comment: Do I have to use setInterval() for that?

Comment: No need to use setInterval you can have only one state at functional component level and you can use that state whenever your timestamp got updated and based on that state you can conditionally use dynamic route as i said earlier

Comment: I understand the logic of states, but my point is how can I detect that for example the Date now timestamp became equal to (1638313200) without a refresh on the page.